# Page redirect does not work but works in Debug mode

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a page with a modal dialog pop up. I want to redirect to another page whenever modal dialog is closed either by clicking on a close button or on the `x` at the top right-hand corner.

first I set a hidden variable P9_URL and use

```
:P9_URL := APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL
 (p_url => 'f?p=' || v('APP_ID') || ':2:' || v('APP_SESSION') || '::' || 
   v('DEBUG') || ':2:::'
   ,p_checksum_type => 'SESSION'
 );
```

in my Page Load dynamic action. Then, in the dynamic action for a button-click I have the following JavaScript:

```
eval($('#P9_URL').val());
```

So now it supposed to close the modal dialog page and redirect to page 2. But when I click the button, nothing happens. So I turn on the debugger and click on the button and it works right away. Could someone shed some light on why this is happening

P.S. I also tried setting P_URL in the button-click dynamic action but still got the same result

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Dialog section of your page? I believe "Chained" has to be set as "Yes"

Comment: just checked. Chained was set to Yes

Comment: how about your browser settings? perhaps it prevents js to close tabs?

Comment: which setting would that be?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put that code in your modal page, in the section "Execute When Page Loads":

```
var button = parent.$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close'); //get the button
button.unbind(); //remove the behavior

//put another behavior to the button, in this case redirect to page 2
button.on('click', function() { 
location.href="f?p=&APP_ALIAS.:2:&SESSION."
});
```

Comment: where is that section? on the modal dialog page itself?

Comment: page properties of your modal page, there is a field called "Execute When Page Loads"